# How can I determine if a string is natural language or an address when searching for a location?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement an apple maps like search bar for users to be able to find a specific location or address and save a pin at that searched location. Now, I understand how to take an address that is in natural language and how to obtain coordinates from an address. But I have no clue how I can efficiently parse a string and know which request to make. I haven't been able to find anything online, only articles on email addresses. Any information that highlights standards / good implementations would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CLGeocoder`to check if a string is a location. You can format your code like this:

```
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if let placemark = placemarks![0] as? CLPlacemark  {
                print("place")
            } else {
                print("string")
            }
        }
```

However, this could be intensive if used on large arrays. But it should be fine for a search bar!

Comment: so pretty much in the worst case, I make two separate requests? per search?

Comment: This code will tell you if it's a properly coded map search or just a string. So in theory you only need to make one request per search, going on the assumption that whatever isn't a location is a string. However, there are totally gray areas here, like if you just searched Jean-Baptiste, I'm not sure if it'd give you a string or a region of Quebec. But it should do the job at least most of the time.

Comment: hmmm, i've typed in "coffee" , "bc place" , "pizza", and "123 main Street, Vancouver, BC" and every single one only told me "place" with what you gave me.

Comment: You're right! Wowza! I'm sorry if I wasted you any time, I really though that that code would work... I'll be deleting this answer...

Comment: Don't worry about it, you were on the right track! instead of what you put inside the closure, you should check if placemark = placemarks?.first , and then after that see if there is an address that is associated with the placemark! I'll post an answer with my solution, using bits from a library / your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both Maclean and [Location Manager by Varshyl Mobile](https://github.com/varshylmobile/LocationManager). NOTE: here is the answer I was able to come up with that sort of solves my problem; still have issues with getting the right natural language location to pop up.

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address as String, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("error")
        }
        else{
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                let address = AddressParser()
                address.parseAppleLocationData(placemark)
                let addressDict = address.getAddressDictionary()
                print("searched address")
                print(addressDict)
            }
            else {
                print("invalid address")
            }
        }

    })
```

And Below is the class / functions that I used from the library mentioned above.

```
private class AddressParser: NSObject{

 private var latitude = NSString()
 private var longitude  = NSString()
 private var streetNumber = NSString()
 private var route = NSString()
 private var locality = NSString()
 private var subLocality = NSString()
 private var formattedAddress = NSString()
 private var administrativeArea = NSString()
 private var administrativeAreaCode = NSString()
 private var subAdministrativeArea = NSString()
 private var postalCode = NSString()
 private var country = NSString()
 private var subThoroughfare = NSString()
 private var thoroughfare = NSString()
 private var ISOcountryCode = NSString()
 private var state = NSString()


override init(){

    super.init()

}

private func getAddressDictionary()-> NSDictionary{

    let addressDict = NSMutableDictionary()

    addressDict.setValue(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    addressDict.setValue(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
    addressDict.setValue(streetNumber, forKey: "streetNumber")
    addressDict.setValue(locality, forKey: "locality")
    addressDict.setValue(subLocality, forKey: "subLocality")
    addressDict.setValue(administrativeArea, forKey: "administrativeArea")
    addressDict.setValue(postalCode, forKey: "postalCode")
    addressDict.setValue(country, forKey: "country")
    addressDict.setValue(formattedAddress, forKey: "formattedAddress")

    return addressDict
}


private func parseAppleLocationData(placemark:CLPlacemark){

    let addressLines = placemark.addressDictionary!["FormattedAddressLines"] as! NSArray

    //self.streetNumber = placemark.subThoroughfare ? placemark.subThoroughfare : ""
    self.streetNumber = (placemark.thoroughfare != nil ? placemark.thoroughfare : "")!
    self.locality = (placemark.locality != nil ? placemark.locality : "")!
    self.postalCode = (placemark.postalCode != nil ? placemark.postalCode : "")!
    self.subLocality = (placemark.subLocality != nil ? placemark.subLocality : "")!
    self.administrativeArea = (placemark.administrativeArea != nil ? placemark.administrativeArea : "")!
    self.country = (placemark.country != nil ?  placemark.country : "")!
    self.longitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude.description;
    self.latitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude.description
    if(addressLines.count>0){
        self.formattedAddress = addressLines.componentsJoinedByString(", ")}
    else{
        self.formattedAddress = ""
    }


}
```

Comment: Excellent work. Now you get the privilege of marking your own answer as solved! ;)

Comment: unfortunately it isn't solved... because i'm still having problems getting the natural language to give me the right location i'm searching for. This is just a... possible starting point for someone else smarter than i :D